# Not getting a django's right capture group when url has a "."

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a url **http://localhost/fault/docs/testing/pipelines/dot.filetesting** which should return a default html page ie index.html

urls.py looks like-   `re_path(r'(?P<resource>.*)$', csrf_exempt(views.get_docs_from_s3), name='read_docs')`

view.py - `

```
@require_GET
def get_docs_from_s3(request, resource):
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(resource)
    # if not Path(resource).suffix:
    #     resource = resource.rstrip("/") + "/index.html"

    try:
        page = get_page_from_s3(resource)
        return HttpResponse(page, content_type=mime_type or "text/html")
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse("Not found", content_type=mime_type or "text/html")`
```

nginx conf - `

```
 location /fault {
       add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
       rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1 permanent;
       proxy_set_header Host localhost:8000;

       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/bug;

       proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
       proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
       proxy_send_timeout 30s;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
     }`
```

Question for a url like http://localhost/fault/docs/testing/pipelines/normal I am able to render html page since the resource in my views = docs/testing/pipelines/normal/index.html but for urls that have **"."** in them like mentioned above I don't get index.html appended.

Note-> In the code I do not want to add /index.html in my views.py for that doesn't have, if its able to be resolved at nginx and django urls leveel